# Installing Imagick PHP Extension on CentOS 6.3 64bit?

Tags: php, centos6, imagemagick

I am trying to configure and make install imagick extension, here is commands that i used

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.0.1.tgz
tar zxf imagick-3.0.1.tgz
cd imagick-3.0.1
phpize
./configure
```

But this error happen :

```
checking for MagickWand.h header file... configure: error: Cannot locate header file MagickWand.h
```

I found MagickWand.h at this location

```
/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand
```

Here is my ImageMagic Version

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.3-7 2013-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP Modules
Delegates: bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype gslib jng jp2 jpeg lcms openexr pango png ps rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Is there any option with configure so i can locate that header file ?

am i installing right version since my php is 5.3 and ImageMagick 6.8.3-7 trying to install imagick-3.0.1 !?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi I also struggle in a half-day that i tried all of things above. But it doesn't work
Finally, I decided to reading the configure file. Therefore, some miss-configurations about Magickwand.h. You should search" wand", for example, and modify the path to point to your specific Magickwand.h To file down where is your MaigickWand, jus run above shell-script snippet...
In my case, in the path, which point to MagickWand.h is missed "6" in Imagick word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pkg-config to locate header file MagickWand.h 
Suppose you install ImageMagick in /usr/local/ImageMagick-6.8.4 and imagick-3.0.1

```
cd imagick-3.0.1
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/ImageMagick-6.8.4/lib/pkgconfig
phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php5/bin/php-config \
--with-imagick=/usr/local/ImageMagick-6.8.4/
make
make install
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you drop your custom compiled PHP and switch over the to the version provided by  [IUS](http://iuscommunity.org/pages/Repos.html).  Specifically, you'd install the following packages after configuring the IUS repo:

php53u php53u-pecl-imagick

This will probably make things significantly easier for you, as you won't have to worry about compiling this module anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tell imagick where the header files are located.

```
./configure --with-imagick=/local
```

Use the help switch to list additional configuration options.

```
./configure --help
```

#### [edit] Confirm Local Install

The configuration script will look for `MagickWand-config` and/or `Wand-config` executable to determine where include headers are located. MagickWand-config is selected by checking if the executable exists in `$PHP_MAGICK/bin/MagickWand-config`; where, **$PHP_MAGICK** is the path provided by `--with-imagick=PATH`, or `/usr/local` or `/usr`.

Here's a quick script to verify your local IM install can be used by PHP Imagick extension.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
IM_CONFIG=`which MagickWand-config`
# Or use different IM location by setting previous line with absolute 
# path to executable config (ie. IM_CONFIG=/local/bin/MagickWand-config)

IM_PREFIX=`$IM_CONFIG --prefix`
if test -r $IM_PREFIX/include/wand/magick-wand.h ; then
  echo "Local IM install has development headers"
else
  echo "Local IM install is missing development headers"
  echo "Try reinstalling source, or 'yum install ImageMagick-devel' package"
fi
```

Comment: I did this `./configure --with-imagick=/local/include/ImageMagick-6 --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config` but still getting same error !?

Comment: Configure should resolve the include path by use of `/local/bin/MagickWand-config`. So `./configure --with-imagick=/local` will be enough

Comment: Still Same `checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... found in /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config
checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... found version 6.8.3 Q16
checking for MagickWand.h header file... configure: error: Cannot locate header file MagickWand.h`

Comment: I really am stuck with this :| , ImageMagick is such a headache

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. And the above ways can't resove it.
I read the configure file and I found the location of `imagickwand.h` is wrong. I resolved it by running the following command:

```
ln -s /usr/local/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick-6 /usr/local/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but I must put my contribution.

If running php 5.4. just run these two lines of code:

```
pear config-set preferred_state beta
pecl install imagick
```

Answer (score -2):

Use 'yum install php-magickwand' after enabling epel repository.  Installing by source on production systems is not a good idea as uninstall, down-grade, upgrade etc. is not supported.

Comment: That gives you the PHP 5.2 version of the module.